# Bluetooth not working on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth

Hey so pretty much what the title says, my BT isnt working, I have tried `rfkill list`, and nothing is blocked.Bluez launches but doesn't do much more than that, since I cant click on anything. Also checked on it with this command `sudo service bluetooth status` and its telling me its active (running) but every time I go to find a device in BT settings and I click the slider to turn it on, the slider goes blue like it is on, but it doesn't actually search for any devices, also I cant find it when I search on my phone. I don't think its really on because when I back out of the BT setting tab and go back into it the slider is in off position, like i never switched it on. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: ah yep sorry wasn't sure how to markdown will do next time, also i don't know about duplicate because bluez launches fine except Im unable to click on anything on its UI. I know this laptop has BT, it was there when it was windows, hasnt worked since linux. Could it be a kernel issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could solve your problem, but it has helped me finding devices that wouldn't appear in Ubuntu bluetooth search a while ago.
This script is used for `bluetooth` connection with wireless headsets.

[Fixing bluetooth stereo headphone/headset problem in ubuntu 16.04, 16.10 and also debian jessie, with bluez5. | gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae)